# How to set focus on first image in my Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi given below code sets focus on last image in my panel.
how do i set it to focus on first image? 
I sort of understand i have to use ID of image button i create on fly. but don't know how.Please help.

```
 var fileIdx = 0;     
foreach (Tripclass Trip in TripsByTripIds )
      {
          fileIdx++;
          ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(){ ID = "imageBtn" + fileIdx };
          imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/" +Trip.CorridorName+"/"+Trip.Time+"/"+Trip.ImgFileName;
          imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
          imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
          imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
          imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
          AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
          AMSPanel1.Height = Unit.Pixel(860);
          imageButton.Focus();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileIdx = 0;     
foreach (Tripclass Trip in TripsByTripIds )
  {
      fileIdx++;
      ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(){ ID = "imageBtn" + fileIdx };
      imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/" +Trip.CorridorName+"/"+Trip.Time+"/"+Trip.ImgFileName;
      imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
      imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
      AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
      AMSPanel1.Height = Unit.Pixel(860);
      if(fileIdx == 1) 
      {
          imageButton.Focus();
      }
  }
```

The only thing changed is this:

From:

```
imageButton.Focus();
```

To:

```
if(fileIdx == 1) 
      {
          imageButton.Focus();
      }
```

Comment: thanks! I figured out that sometime ago but didn't have time to come back and post answer! but what a brilliant solution!

Comment: @avi, Glad you found it useful.  If the answer solves your problem, mark it complete, will help others to know that this is the accepted answer :)

Comment: @avi, little grey check mark next to the rating of the answer.  Once you mark it complete - it will turn green, I think.